# Set success and error responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an ajax request in my angular code for signing users in via my API:

```
$http.post(LOGIN, {
    username: username,
    password: password
}).success(function(response){
    console.log('response:')
    console.log(response);
    console.log('_________')
}).error(function(response){
    console.log('response:')
    console.log(response);
    console.log('_________')
})}
```

It works perfectly, apart from that `response` variable. If the success is triggered, the local `response` variable is set to an empty string (not undefined), and if the failure is triggered, that `response` variable is set to an empty string.

Here's what I get in my console:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sessions 401 (Unauthorized) 
response:

_________
```

And if I return a 200 status:

```
response:

_________
```

Here is my serverside rails code:

```
def login
    status = :unauthorized
    status = :ok if User.find_by(username: session_params[:username]).try(:authenticate, session_params[:password])
    head status
end
```

In the book I'm reading we actually show the error response to the user. How should I alter my serverside code so that `response` is populated with an actual message? Or should I alter my clientside code in someway?

Answer (score 0):

According to [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) (section Returns) success and error receive next properties:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {}
```

So you see that first param is data and status is the second one. You do not return any data. To get status code you have to do next:

```
.success(function(data, status){
    console.log('response:')
    console.log(data + ' ' + status);
    console.log('_________')
```